# Cannot get next-auth v5 to work even following official tutorial closely

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am new to nextjs and next-auth, I am trying to learn from this tutorial, it uses next-auth v5: https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication

I got login page and it verifies credentials correctly, but it goes back to login page again.

I checked authorize function and it returns user object currently, but received null in auth parameter. I force returned true in authorize but it returns some other error and it's not current way anyway.

I can't post my code currently because I don't have my pc right now, but my code is exactly same as this tutorial I checked multiple times, just few changes in import where tutorial had incorrect path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same issue.
But, add `AUTH_URL` to `.env` and then solved.

Here, Github Link.

https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/issues/321